# How to capture socket objects into external constant in Jetty 9 (migrating from Jetty 7)?

Tags: java, sockets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm migrating a web application with embedded Jetty from 7 to 9.3.2 and as such am in need of updating the code a little. The application itself has a multitude of connectors written for it, for web UI, API endpoint and also for authenticating to the web interface via a smart card. The connector method for achieving that is implemented as follows (for Jetty 7).

```
private Connector createSmartCardConnector() {
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = createSslContextFactory(smartCardUiKeyStoreFile);

LOG.info("Using truststore file: " + trustStoreFile);
sslContextFactory.setTrustStore(trustStoreFile);
sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword("password");
sslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true);

Connector connector = new SslSocketConnector(sslContextFactory) {
  @Override public void accept(int acceptorID) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Socket socket = _serverSocket.accept();
    configure(socket);
    SslConnectorEndPoint connection = new SslConnectorEndPoint(socket);
    SMART_CARD_SOCKETS.add((SSLSocket) socket);
    connection.dispatch();
  }
};
```

As is apparent from the code, the `SslSocketConnector.accept()` method is overridden and the only part that is added is `SMART_CARD_SOCKETS.add((SSLSocket) socket);`. `SMART_CARD_SOCKETS` is a set that is later used for destroying the objects (sockets) being added to it. My question here is how to achieve the same functionality in Jetty 9, the point of which is that when the smart card is removed from the user's computer, the socket would be destroyed when the user attempts to navigate further.

I have tried to override the `ServerConnector.accept()` method in Jetty 9, however it uses a private method in it, which makes this impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a custom implementation of [`HttpConfiguration.Customizer`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpConfiguration.Customizer.html).

Add it to your `HttpConfiguration` for the `ServerConnector` you are interested in, and then it will run with each accept.

Example use of [`SecureRequestCustomizer.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.2.v20150730/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/SecureRequestCustomizer.java).

```java
    // Setup SSL
    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("/path/to/keystore");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("password");

    // Setup HTTPS Configuration
    HttpConfiguration httpsConf = new HttpConfiguration();
    httpsConf.setSecurePort(8443);
    httpsConf.setSecureScheme("https");
    httpsConf.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer()); // adds ssl info to request

    // Establish the ServerConnector
    ServerConnector httpsConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,"http/1.1"),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConf));
    httpsConnector.setPort(httpsPort);

    server.addConnector(httpsConnector);
```

Comment: I looked at trying to create the custom implementation but I'm unsure how to capture the socket in it. I'm guessing I'm supposed to add it into the customize() method? Or should I not be doing it like this at all?

Comment: Yes, look at the `customize()` method.  The `SecureRequestCustomizer` link above has an example.  However, you'll want to reevaluate WHY you need a Socket (its not for the raw Socket, as using that in Jetty 7 was highly dangerous).  You probably only need the metadata for the TLS/SSL connection.  There's no longer raw Sockets accessible, Jetty dropped traditional IO for NIO a few years ago.  You'll have to work with either the NIO Channel, the SSLSession, or the SSLEngine to obtain what you need.

Comment: Rereading your question, I think you would benefit from hanging onto the `EndPoint` object and just issuing [`EndPoint.close()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/io/EndPoint.html#close--) on it to harshly close the active connections.